# ASP.NET Core web api serialize an object's List type property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

After the server returned the object, the List type field went missing.

Each `EmployeeViewModel` has a list of `EmployeeContactViewModel` objects. The intended logic is, after querying the employee object from database, populate the view model in a method, including the list, and return to client.

The view model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public List<EmployeeContactViewModel> EmployeeContacts;

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        EmployeeContacts = new List<EmployeeContactViewModel>();
    }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    // more fields
}
```

The method to populate view models:

```
    public EmployeeViewModel GetViewModelFromEmpObject()
    {
        var vm = new EmployeeViewModel();

        var contact1 = this.CONTACTs.Where(e => e.ContactId == 1).FirstOrDefault();

        if (contact1 != null)
        {
            var contactVm1 = new EmployeeContactViewModel();
            CopyContactFields(contact1, contactVm1);    // method to populate view-model
            vm.EmployeeContacts.Add(contactVm1);
        }
        else 
            vm.EmployeeContacts.Add(new EmployeeContactViewModel());

        var contact2 = this.CONTACTs.Where(e => e.ContactId == 2).FirstOrDefault();

        if (contact2 != null)
        {
            var contactVm2 = new EmployeeContactViewModel();
            CopyContactFields(contact1, contactVm2);    // method to populate view-model
            vm.EmployeeContacts.Add(contactVm2);
        }
        else 
            vm.EmployeeContacts.Add(new EmployeeContactViewModel());

        // more lines below
    }
```

The api controller method is below. By setting a breakpoint at the return line, I could see the `EmployeeContactViewModel` list was correctly created.

```
[HttpGet("{empid:string}")]
public async Task<EmployeeViewModel> GetAsync(string empid)
{
    Employee emp = await _context.Employees
                                 .Include(c => c.CONTACTs)
                                 .Where(c => c.EmployeeId == empid)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var viewModel = emp.GetViewModelFromEmpObject();

    return viewModel;
}
```

However on the client side, although all the other fields (`EmployeeId`, `EmployeeName`, etc.) were present in the response, there was nothing for `EmployeeContacts` list, when inspecting the server response in the browser network tab.

I tried to search before asking but using "Serialize" as a keyword would just get topics on how to do serialization. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `e.ContactId == 1` is that true??

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes each employee has it.

Comment: What effect do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that `EmployeeContacts` is not included in the response result?

You can install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, and add this line in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```